# Fermi Level Shift in PN Junction

Tags: semiconductor-physics, boundary-conditions, fermi-energy

The image below shows the Fermi level shift of the PN junction when the potential of the N region is positive with respect to the P region. My textbook  (Semiconductor physics and devices by Donald A. Neamen, 4th edition) states that the Fermi energy in the N region is lower than that of the P region. How does this make sense? From what I understand, the Fermi energy is the highest energy state which contains electrons. Therefore, wouldn't applying a larger potential at the N-side increase the Fermi energy at the N-side rather than at the P-side? I understand how the potential barrier gets larger but I don't understand why the Fermi level is lower at the N-side?

[[image: This]]

Comment: Under bias, of course.

Comment: Yes, what do you mean? I get it's under bias but that does not really answer my question.

Comment: If the device is not in equilibrium, why would you expect the Fermi level to be constant?

Comment: When did I say I expect it to be constant? My question is why is the Fermi energy at the P-side greater than at the N-side, and not the other way around?

Answer (score 0):

Electrons have negative charge, so the positive potential of the $N$ region means a negative energy term for the electron states at the $N$-side.

This is because "potential" here means the electric potential $V$, which is opposite to the "potential energy" in the energy picture. So it's actually a language problem.